# Ubuntu shell script menu

Tags: ubuntu

I am new to shell scripting/ programming. I want to create a menu that shows the following: list files, time and date, calendar, password file and exit. User should be able to enter their choice and script responds. Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((choice 1=5))
do
   clear
   echo "1. List all files"; echo
   echo "2. Display date and time"; echo
   echo "3. Calendar"; echo
   echo "4. Passwd file"; echo
   echo "5. Exit"; echo
   echo -n "Enter choice"

   read choice
   case $choice in
   1) ls -l;;
   2) date;;
   3) cal;;
   4) cat /etc/passwd;;
   5) echo "Thanks and goodbye!";;
   *) echo "1..5 only"
   esac
   sleep 3
done
```